# How to debug wild pointer (exc_bad_access)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, debugging

[image]

Can't locate ~!
enable zombie objects!

Comment: this link might be useful http://stackoverflow.com/a/1213121/5362916

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! Could you please describe your problem more in words? Image only questions are not the best ones. Also, this may help to narrow down your issue and thus improve your question : http://blog.manbolo.com/2012/01/23/xcode-tips-1-break-on-exceptions